# Is there a .NET library for standardizing my images / documents to PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, document-converter

I need to be able to import and process a variety of different images and documents. I need a tool or library that will ingest the file and perform OCR if necessary, but save it out as a standardized PDF file for archiving purposes (PDF/A). Is there a tool or .NET library that can achieve this? If the document is already searchable, it should not OCR it again.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider trying the [Leadtools SDK](http://www.Leadtools.com). Their [DocumentConverter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/doxc/documentconverter.html) is designed especially for this type of workflow. You can take any [document](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/ft/documentformat.html) or [image format](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/l/rasterimageformat.html), vector based or raster, and convert to any other document or image format, and OCR is performed automatically based on your settings. Below you can find a quick snippet for converting a directory of various files to PDF documents in another directory. Just as a disclaimer, I work for the vendor of this product.

```
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{
    string inputDirectory = @"C:\temp\input files";
    string outputDirectory = @"C:\temp\output documents";
    string[] inputFiles = Directory.GetFiles(inputDirectory);

    // Required for document output
    var documentWriter = new DocumentWriter();
    documentConverter.SetDocumentWriterInstance(documentWriter);

    // Optional for Raster -> Searchable Vector
    var ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD);
    ocrEngine.Startup(null, documentWriter, null, null);
    documentConverter.SetOcrEngineInstance(ocrEngine, true);

    // Look through each file in the input directory
    foreach (var filename in inputFiles)
    {
        // Create a DocumentConverterJobData that holds the necessary information
        var jobData = new DocumentConverterJobData();
        jobData.InputDocumentFileName = filename;
        jobData.DocumentFormat = DocumentFormat.Pdf;
        jobData.OutputDocumentFileName = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + ".pdf");

        // Create a job with the necessary jobData and execute it
        var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
        documentConverter.Jobs.RunJobAsync(job);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @JClark742, thank you for your answer. I have a couple follow up questions:
Is this a commercial library? If so, where can I see pricing and can I try it for free before buying? Does this work cross platform via .NET 5? Is there a Nuget library I can use?

Comment: LEADTOOLS is a commercial library that you can download and try for free here: https://www.leadtools.com/downloads. You can also find our NuGet packages here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Document.Sdk/. This is supported on .NET and you can find our basic pricing outline here: https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/product-overview.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion’s Essential PDF ([.NET PDF library](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net)) supports OCR by using the Tesseract open-source engine. A scanned paper document containing raster images is converted to a searchable and selectable document with a few lines of code. Please refer to the below links for more information,

**UG**: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-ocr/dot-net-framework

**KB**: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9144/how-to-convert-scanned-image-to-searchable-pdf-by-processing-ocr

**NuGet information**: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/nuget-packages-required#pdf-ocr

Please refer the below code snippet to OCR a PDF document and save with PDF/A1b conformance.

```
using Syncfusion.OCRProcessor;

using Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing;

using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"../../Tesseract_bin/x86/");

        using (OCRProcessor processor = new OCRProcessor(path))

        {
            processor.Settings.TesseractVersion = TesseractVersion.Version4_0;
            //Load a PDF document 

            PdfLoadedDocument lDoc = new PdfLoadedDocument("../../Region.pdf");

            lDoc.Conformance = Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfConformanceLevel.Pdf_A1B;

            //Set OCR language to process 

            processor.Settings.Language = Languages.English;

            
            //Process OCR by providing the PDF document and tesseract data, and enabling the isMemoryOptimized property

            processor.PerformOCR(lDoc, @"../../LanguagePack/", true);

            //Save the OCR processed PDF document in the disk 

            lDoc.Save("Sample.pdf");

            lDoc.Close(true);

        }
    }
```

We have also provided the support for [PDF to PDF/A conversion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-pdf-conformance#pdf-to-pdfa-conversion) in our Syncfusion PDF library, please refer the below link,

**PDF to PDF/A**: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-pdf-conformance#pdf-to-pdfa-conversion

**More PDF Examples**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/PDF/Default#/material

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

**Note**: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,

Gowtham